# Control hardware via php

Tags: php, hardware

I am trying to control my COM port directly via PHP. I have a Linux ubuntu server and LAMP. I use this php serial class to communicate with the port (http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/). My question is how can I turn on lights using this port? How can I convert COM port signal to electricity signal?

Comment: You have to know what message the receiver is looking for (i.e. you need to know a lot about the hardware.) The hardware will then create the electricity. See, the board on the hardware, takes the information you give it and then flips gates on and off.

Comment: Can you give me example scheme which can turn on the lights and what exactly I have to send to COM port to see this result?

Comment: I honestly can't, I don't know anything about the hardware.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to some more research about the hardware you are trying to control. Unfortunately, it is not possible to give you any sort of code example when we don't even know what the device is you are trying to control.

Comment: The device which I am trying to control is a led. I am trying to turn on this led using my com port on desktop computer. Do you understand my idea?

Comment: I'm not sure why this got voted up. What lights are you trying to control? If it's the lights in your house, you need something like an X-10 adapter. The other option is to build your own hardware with an Arduino (or other microcontroller) that can drive relays to turn lights on or off. If you go the build your own route, you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: I want to turn on lights like this http://www.robotev.com/popup_image.php?pID=167  In this case can you give me example scheme or give me more information what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

if the hardware already had an cli application to control it, have php run the cli application with `exec()` ... it's a way easier short cut

Comment: Give me example because I am very confused. What I have to send via php and on which pins on com port I have to wait for electricity signal?

Comment: all i said/asked was... does your hardware already already come with some software or drivers... and can you use those drivers directly from command line?

Comment: No I don`t have drivers, I just have a PC with OS ubuntu server.